How to prove a competitor is infringing if a step happens in the back server?
Let's suppose that you have a patent claim that involves a step that happens in the back end server rather than the front end user interface.
Since you do not know what is happening in the back end server of your competitor, how can you prove the competitor is infringing?

Not a full answer, but that is why it is advisable to write claims in a way that infringement can be shown from publicly available information, like solely through interaction with their application through the public interface. When that can't be done there is a process called "discovery" that will require your competitor to disclose how the relevant parts of their system work to your legal team. However I don't know very well what the requirements are to get discovery going (presumably there are checks and balances to prevent fishing for information via frivolous lawsuits).
